# Are there "standard" events for cookies in web browsers?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is there a way to know when a cookie has changed without using an interval, perhaps with some standard event?

*Aside* this is for a single page app, making various ajax calls at any given time that might bump up the cookie expiration.

Comment: Personally, I believe that there is no such option. Same for local storage. And I too wish for check for changes of both of theese without polling.

Comment: No, but it should be enough to check after each of those ajax requests instead of using an interval. And of course you can trigger a custom event then.